# HQL equivalent for additional conditions in LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, hql

I have hibernate entities:

- Organization (has 2 ManyToMany mappings for persons (list of regular persons, and list of privilegend persons))
- Person

Is there a way to make HQL equivalent for this query?

```
    select distinct p.id, p.lastAndFirstName
    from organizations o
    left join organization2person op on op.organization_id=o.id
    left join organization2privileged_person opp on opp.organization_id=o.id
    left join sys_persons p on p.id=op.person_id or p.id=opp.person_id
    order by p.lastAndFirstName
```

I don't know how to create condition `p.id=op.person_id or p.id=opp.person_id` in the last left join.
I have seen `WITH` keyword, but it creates condition with "AND", not "OR".

Comment: It is all about the mapping. And since you don't say what your classes are it doesn't make sense to ask how to make a HQL query. What hql query did you try and what was wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look something like this.

Based on the very scant details it sounds like you want subqueries. But you might consider reverse mapping these associations from the Person side. It might not be more efficient but it might make your life easier.

```
select p.id, p.lastAndFirstName from Person p
   where p.id in
   (select p2.id from Organization o 
        left join op.persons p2)
   or p.id in
   (select p3.id 
       left join o.privilegedPersons p3)
```

(PS. I can't figure out what you are trying to do with sys_persons)

Comment: Thanks. Actually I redesigned those objects, so I merged "privilegedPersons" and "persons" into one object, mapping with composite PK and with boolean flag (signalig whether it is privileged person or not). This mapping is little bit more complicated, but queries are more simple on the other hand.

Comment: And "sys_persons" is just table with persons (id, login, email, name, etc.)